# Single empty and suggestion templates for multiple Typeahead Datasets

Tags: twitter-typeahead

I've been trying to combine several functions [in typeahead plugin](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) particularly multiple-datasets + empty + default suggestions. No luck so far, hope someone could help

Right now, to make it work, it's a choice between multiple-datasets ---OR--- empty + default suggestions

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/16x3cnq7/4/)

My HTML

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback" id="citydiv">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="city">City / Provinces<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-sm-4" id="multiple-datasets">
  <input id="cities" name="cities" class="typeahead form-control" type="text">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

MY Javascript

```
var city1 = ['a','b','c','d'];
var city2 = ['e','f','g','h'];
var city3 = ['i','j','k','l'];
var city4 = ['m','n','o','p'];


$('#multiple-datasets .typeahead').typeahead({
  highlight: true,
  hint: true,
  minLength: 1,
},
{
  source: substringMatcher(city1),
  templates: {
    header: '<h4>city1</h4>'
  }
},
{
  source: substringMatcher(city2),
  templates: {
    header: '<h4>city2</h4>'
  }
},
{
  source: substringMatcher(city3),
  templates: {
    header: '<h4>city3</h4>'
  }
},
{
  source: substringMatcher(city4),
  templates: {
    header: '<h4>city4</h4>'
  }
});
```

Comment: There is an issue about that on GitHub: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/780

Answer (score 0):

First, I wrapped the input in a div to easily get back to the parent:

```
$(element).wrap('<div class="my-typeahead"></div>');
```

Second, you will need to add a special class to the notFound messages div. This will need to be applied to all datasets. I chose tt-none:

```
templates: {
    notFound: '<div class="tt-suggestion tt-none">There are no results for your search.</div>',
}
```

Next, I added a listener on the typeahead:render:

```
...
.on('typeahead:render', function(e, objs, async, name) {
    var nones = $(element).find('.tt-none');
    var suggestions = $(element).find('.tt-suggestion.tt-selectable').length;

    // Hide all notFound messages
    nones.hide();
    // Only show the first message if there are zero results available
    if(suggestions === 0) {
        nones.first().show();
    }

});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I required for working with typeahead.js with multiple datasets.

**1. Add an empty template to one dataset**

```
templates: {
    empty: '<div class="empty-message">No results</div>'
}
```

**2. Add event trigger keyup for the typeahead input field (.tt-input)**
When there is more than 0 suggestions, we hide the empty-message.

```
$(document).on('keyup', ".tt-input", function(event) {

    if($(".tt-suggestion").length){
        $(".empty-message").hide();
    }

});
```